# Bounds for expected values.

Tags: probability

Let's take two values $q_1,q_2 \ge 0$ such that $q_1+q_2 \le 1$, and three non negative reals $u_1,u_2,u$.

Assume that $q_1 u_1 + q_2 u_2 \le (q_1+q_2)u$.

Does this imply

$q_1 A^{u_1} + q_2 A^{u_2} \ge (q_1+q_2) A^u$

for all $0 < A < 1$?

Thanks for your effort and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, follows from the convexity of $A^u$ for $0< A < 1$. Let $\frac{q1}{q1 + q2} u_1 + \frac{q2}{q1 + q2} u_2  = v$; $\lambda = \frac{q1}{q1 + q2}$

Then from convexity of $A^x$,

$\lambda A^{u_1} + (1 -\lambda) A^{u_2} < A^v$; and if $u > v, A^v > A^u$.

Comment: Hi Sun, many thanks for your help!